# I'm attempting to put my logo animation in the center of the page, but the positioning gets all messed up

Tags: html, css

Originally, just for the logo alone, I used fixed positioning since the divs for each square would not be in the right place otherwise. With a fixed position, they won't go into my inner div box though. The inner and outer div boxes have colour just so I can see them at the moment. Does anyone know of a way to make the position for my divs relative whiel still keeping them in the right position for the animation so they cross over and are symmetrical?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    div.outer {
      top: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      background-color: red;
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    div.inner {
        width: 60%;
        height: 60%;
        top: 25%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        background:orange;
    }

    body {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
    }

    div.a {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: blue;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: raveA;
      animation-duration: 2.5s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    div.b {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: raveB;
      animation-duration: 2.5s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    div.c {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: green;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: raveC;
      animation-duration: 2.5s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    div.d {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
      animation-name: raveD;
      animation-duration: 2.5s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes raveA {
      0% {background-color:blue; left:0px; top:0px;}
      50% {background-color:red; left:230px; top:230px;}
      100% {background-color:rgb(240,101,43); left:55px; top:20px; transform:skewX(-10deg);}
    }

    @keyframes raveB {
      0% {background-color:red; left:250px; top:250px;}
      50% {background-color:yellow; left:20px; top:20px;}
      100% {background-color:rgb(247,189,0); left:230px; top:230px; transform:skewX(-10deg);}
    }

    @keyframes raveC {
      0% {background-color:green; left:0px; top:250px;}
      50% {background-color:blue; left:230px; top:20px;}
      100% {background-color:rgb(0,174,233); left:20px; top:230px; transform:skewX(-10deg);}
    }

    @keyframes raveD {
      0% {background-color:yellow; left:250px; top:0px;}
      50% {background-color:green; left:20px; top:230px;}
      100% {background-color:rgb(140,189,0); left:265px; top:20px; transform:skewX(-10deg);}
    }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="a"></div>
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
        <div class="d"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```